# Going through rooms in a text based game in Java

Tags: java, text, arraylist

I hope this isn't too amateurish for you guys but I'm having a hard time creating a small text-based game in Java using objects. So far I've wrote classes for Player, Item(this will be for later use, for now I have simpler goals), Room, Inventory(again, for later use) and the Main Class. What should I use to keep track of my location? I want to go through locations back-and-forth like in Zork (example go north, go south etc.) I thought about using an ArrayList that would contain every location, but again this stumbles me even more. What I wrote so far:

```
class Player{
    //int healthPoints; for later use
    private String playerName;
    public void setPlayerName(String playerNameParam)
    {
        playerName=playerNameParam;
    }
    public String getPlayerName(){
        return playerName;
    }


}
class Item{
    private String itemName;
    public void setItemName(String itemNameParam)
    {
        itemName=itemNameParam;
    }
    public String getItemName()
    {
        return itemName;
    }
}
class ExitRoom{

}
class Room{
    private String roomName;
    public void setRoomName(String roomNameParam){
        roomName=roomNameParam;
    }
    public String getRoomName(){
        return roomName;
    }
    private String roomDescription;
    public void setRoomDescription(String roomDescriptionParam){
        roomDescription=roomDescriptionParam;
    }
    public String getRoomDescription(){
        return roomDescription;
    }

}
class Inventory{
    private ArrayList<Item> items= new ArrayList<Item>();
    public boolean findItem(String itemToFind)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<items.size();i++){
            if(items.get(i).getItemName()==itemToFind){
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
public class Main {

     public static void main(String[] args){ 
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
      Player player = new Player();
      boolean gameRunning=true;
      while(gameRunning){
      System.out.println("Welcome to TextBasedGamev1!"
                       + "Before beginning, please enter your name");
      String name=scanner.nextLine();
      player.setPlayerName(name);

      Room forestWelcome=new Room();
      Room forestSouth=new Room();
      Room forestNorth=new Room();
      Room abandonedHouse=new Room();

      }
```

Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the aproach is using a matrix with each cell and a Point to mark the position of the player, for example

```
    Class Map {
        private Room[][] matrix;
        private Player player;
        ...
    }

    class Player{
        private Point position;
        ....
    }
```

Comment: And after I should add if's in class Map for every direction?
Example: if (playerchoice=north) go room[2][1] (considering 2,1 points to north?

Comment: you will probably have a switch(direction) ... case(NORTH): position.y--; matrix[position.x][position.y].playerEntering(player);

Answer (score 2):

A possible approach (not necessarily the best) would be to store in each room the connections to other rooms. For example:

```
enum Direction {
    NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST;
}

class Room {
    private Map<Direction, Room> connections;

    ...

}
```

Comment: Constructing a maze this way takes more time, but plus points are that you can create a *free-form* layout: not only N, S, E, W but also "NE", "up", "down" and "the left door in the North wall" -- and one-way doors, and even doors that "return" to yet another place.

Answer (score 0):

Text adventures are actually state machines.

You might want to look at the 3 free chapters of the book I've been writing on Artificial Intelligence in C# for Games, as it covers this and Java and C# are quite similar.

http://unseenu.wikispaces.com/Game+AI+in+C-Sharp